# Replace/remove Bind for improved security

Tags: bind

I see that BIND gets endless security updates. Are there any alternative services that are not written in C/C++ that can be installed instead of it on desktop Ubuntu? Maybe I don't need BIND at all and can remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
dpkg -l | grep 'dnsutils\|bind9utils\|dnsutils\|maas-dns\|samba\|autodns-dhcp\|bind9-dyndb-ldap|\bindgraph\|cobbler\|collectd-core\|dhis-dns-engine\|dhis-tools-dns\|dlz-ldap-enum\|dms-core\|dnssec-tools\|freeipa-server\|gadmin-bind\|ikiwiki-hosting-dns\|ldap2dns\|ldap2zone\|bind9:i386\|bind9utils:i386\|dnsutils:i386\|bind9utils\|dnsutils\|maas-dns\|bind9:i386\|bind9utils:i386\|dnsutils:i386\|dnsutils'
```

This will list all the packages that depend on `bind9` that are installed on your system. If you are okay with uninstalling these packages, go ahead and uninstall it.

Also, do you need a DNS server? If so, [you may want to look into something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software)

There's `pdnsd`, `unbound`, `dnsmasq`, and `pdns` (PowerDNS) just to name a few.

It looks like PowerDNS has the most features to compete with BIND.

To list the available PowerDNS packages, run the following command:

```
apt-cache search pdns | grep "pdns-"
```

Comment: Looks like it is only samba libraries who uses that. I wonder if they can use a different DNS client library? Something like `update-alternatives`, but for libs.